# python, % and mysql statements

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a mysql query, which needs to contain % characters...  While building the query, I run into a problem of python using % and trying to stick it as a variable:

```
statmt="select id from %s WHERE `email` LIKE %blah%" % (tbl)
self.cursor.execute(statmt)
```

This naturally barfs with:

```
statmt="select id from %s WHERE `email` LIKE %blah%" % (tbl)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

How should I fix this so Python stops reading this as a variable, and takes it in as part of the string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When needing a literal `%` inside a Python formatting expression, use `%%`:

```
statmt="select id from %s WHERE `email` LIKE '%%blah%%'" % (tbl)
```

See the documentation [section 5.6.2. String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for more information.

Comment: Now, what if blah needed to be a "...  ie.... SELECT id from tbl WHERE `email` LIKE %"%

Comment: To escape a literal `"` inside a Python double-quoted string, use `\"`. Or, you can use triple-quoted strings, `"""where you can "quote" things easily"""`.

Comment: If I do that...: statmt="select id from %s WHERE `email` LIKE %%\"%%" % (tbl), I get an error:_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'%"%\' at line 1')

Comment: Well MySQL probably still requires single quotes around the string, `LIKE '%%\"%%'` and not just `LIKE %%\"%%` (I've updated my answer to reflect correct MySQL usage).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use string interpolation.  The execute method handles it for you, so you can do this instead:

```
statmt="select id from %s WHERE `email` LIKE %blah%"
self.cursor.execute(statmt, tbl)
```

Answer (score 2):

you should escape your percent sign with `%%`

You should probably user parameterized queries though with `?` and `,` instead of string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
statmt="select id from {tbl} WHERE `email` LIKE %blah%".format(tbl=tbl)
```

Make sure you're not creating a SQL injection vulnerability.